# What does notation $\inf_{k,l}$ mean for indices $k,l$?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

What does notation $\inf_{k,l}$ mean for indices $k,l$?

Does it mean that one picks $\inf k$ and $\inf l$ or that one picks some kind of "inf of both $k$ and $l$" (whatever that means)?

Comment: It probably means you are taking the infimum over $k$ and $l$, for something that's a function of $k$ and $l$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth $k,l$ are indices as I said. So one can for example assume that $k \in \{1,2,...,n\},l \in \{1,2,...,n\}$. But is the $\inf$ then $1$ and $1$ or $(1,1)$? And if it's $(1,1)$, then this being $\inf$ may not be trivial, because what's the measure?

Comment: In that case, it would be the minimum value of the function for $k,l\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. You must have a function or set or something that you are taking the inf of. For example $\inf\limits_{k,l}a_{k,l}$, where $A=(a_{k,l})$ is some given matrix.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Ah you mean that it asks to "select $k,l$ such that the expression after $\inf$ attains its $\inf$"?

Comment: Almost, but $\inf\limits_{k,l}a_{k,l}$ does not refer to picking the $k,l$, rather it refers to what this infimal value of $a_{k,l}$ is. For example, if $A=(a_{k,l})$ is a matrix whose least entry is $-2$, then $\inf\limits_{k,l}a_{k,l}=-2$.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the context clearly explains a different convention I would expect
$$ \inf_{k,l} f(k,l) $$
to mean the infimum of the set
$$ \{ f(k,l) \mid (k,l)\in K\times L \}$$
which is hopefully a subset of $\mathbb R$ or some other ordered set where you can speak of infima.

You'll need to deduce from the context what the index sets $K$ and $L$ are.

Note that if there are infinitely many possible $k$s or $l$s, the set above can be infinite, and in that case "infimum" may not be the same as "minimum"